# How to enable auto redeploy in vertx when using intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, vert.x, hotdeploy, autodeploy

How to enable auto redeploy in vertx application code when running in intellij idea?

Intellij Settings for hot deployment of vertx application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a Run configuration (Application), set the Main class to io.vertx.core.Launcher. In the Program arguments write: run your-verticle-fully-qualified-name --redeploy=**/*.class --launcher-class=io.vertx.core.Launcher. To trigger the redeployment, you need to make the project or the module explicitly (Build menu → Make project).

Comment: the only problem that if you run some verticle from the launcher then there is not way to debug it in IDE.