# Vertx redeploy feature can not debug if it is run from the Launcher

Tags: java, intellij-idea, vert.x

from http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/

the **Live Redeploy** section.

```
java io.vertx.core.Launcher run org.acme.MyVerticle --redeploy="**/*.class"  --launcher-class=io.vertx.core
.Launcher -cp ...
```

Then if I want to debug MyVerticle from IDE (IntelliJ IDE) I can not not do it. Seems the launcher launch it out of the "context" in different class loader?..

The question is: How to debug a Verticle in IDE that was launched by the Launcher ?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45445891/how-to-enable-auto-redeploy-in-vertx-when-using-intellij

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in the [Live Redeploy](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_live_redeploy) section of the docs:

> To debug your application, create your run configuration as a remote
>   application and configure the debugger using --java-opts. However,
>   don’t forget to re-plug the debugger after every redeployment as a new
>   process is created every time.

So adding something like this should do the trick:

```
--java-opts="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I guess it is a bug. In the interim I use the deprecated `io.vertx.core.Starter` for debugging instead of `io.vertx.core.Launcher`. I know that this answer isn't really satisfactory, but maybe it will help temporarily.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from simply copying the `Launcher` class and rewriting parts of it as you see fit.